# Implementing new permission in Android M

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.1-nougat

I am trying to migrate applications developed with KitKat as target version to Nougat. I want to implement the new Permission features. My application needs few of the dangerous permissions to be pre granted (while install time). How do I do that ? Will placing the application in priv-app folder do the job ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }



public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```